# Opening several websites in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, web-scraping

Fairly new to C#.

I have written a web scraper to collect data from a website. It is impossible to retrieve the data from the HTML since the data I want is displayed via JavaScript or something, so I need to access the rendered website using the WebBrowser. This excludes using e.g. the WebClient class.

I want to collect the data from 10 different pages on the website over a period of one hour, but the code beneath only permits me to do 2 at a time. If I start a third program, the first one just stops. After googling I tried to fix this by adding

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;
```

but this did absolutely nothing.

I am still in development, so right now I am running a seperate Windows Form for every page I am scraping.

Here is my code:
(I have added the A-variable because the site completes loading 4 times).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //GLOBAL VARIABLES
    int A = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunProgram();
    }

    void RunProgram()
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;

        Uri link1 = new Uri("http://www.somesite.com/sdf4575gfn");

        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.AllowNavigation = true;
        wb.Navigate(link1);

        wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
    }

    //WebSite loaded
    private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;

        A = A + 1;

        String content = "";

        if (A == 4)
        {
            wb.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
            wb.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
            content = Clipboard.GetText();
            //Store to file
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just loop through your URL's?  Creating WebBrowsers and then destroying them as you swap URL's?  I don't really understand the question.

Comment: I want to collect data every 2 seconds for one hour so I need the WebBrowsers to run simultaneously. That was an important point I didn't make clear! Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to get it working thanks to the suggestions that were made. Thanks to everyone that contributed.

Here is a trimmed down version of my code. It should work for you if you change the siteID and clean up the code a little.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebBrowserTesting
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        //siteID
        string[] siteID =
        {
            "http://www.somesite.com/3jhurjkrtukty",
            "http://www.somesite.com/dfb87uhs89h7df9g",
            "http://www.somesite.com/mfg5t456rj"

        };

        //Event counters
        int K1 = 0;
        int K2 = 0;
        int K3 = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            runProgram();
        }

        void runProgram()
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < siteID.Length; k++)
            {
                WebBrowser wb1 = new WebBrowser();

                Uri url1 = new Uri(siteID[k]);

                wb1.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;
                wb1.Navigate(url1);
            }
        }

        void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            WebBrowser inner = sender as WebBrowser;
            int counter = updateCounter(inner.Url.ToString());



            if (K1/3 == 4 || K2/3 == 4 || K3/3 == 4) //-------- Mysterious bug
            {
                //In my case the page isn't loaded until the fourth event
                //Here the page is fully loaded. Starting a new thread
                Crawler page = new Crawler();
                Thread oThread = new Thread(() => page.scraper(inner));
                oThread.Start();
            }
        }

        //Page isn't loaded until the DocumentCompleted Event has fired 4 times.
        int updateCounter(string kid)
        {
            int num = 99;

            for (int k = 0; k < siteID.Length; k++)
            {
                if(String.Compare(kid, siteID[0]) == 0)
                {

                    K1 = K1 + 1;
                    num = K1;
                }
                else if (String.Compare(kid, siteID[1]) == 0)
                {
                    K2 = K2 + 1;
                    num = K2;

                }
                else if (String.Compare(kid, siteID[2]) == 0)
                {
                    K3 = K3 + 1;
                    num = K3;

                }
            }
            return num;
        }

    }

    public class Crawler
    {
        public void scraper(WebBrowser inn)
        {

            int life = 0;

            //Primitive loop for testing purposes
            while (life < 1000)
            {
                if (life % 10 == 0 && life > 1)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);

                    inn.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                        inn.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
                        inn.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
                        string content = Clipboard.GetText();
                        Console.WriteLine("Content : " + content);
                        //write content to file

                    }));

                }
                life = life + 1;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After each time you get the data, dispose the webbrowser and then reuse it for each url. Loop through all of your urls and you'll get a near-simultaneous screen scrape. Also, what's wrong with making more instances of webbrowser and staggering their screens scrapes?

Comment: The page I am loading from changes over time, so it would be a lot of work to change the program to handle those changes. It would be easier to just load the page at the beginning and copy the content every 2 seconds. I was hoping there was an easy way to handle several websites, but if not I might try something like this.

As for the instances: I am running the program in multiple exe-files. Surely this would count as different instances?

Comment: Are you trying to go to a webpage and copy off of it's text? That's a get request and you can use a webrequest (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307023) to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, I just need the text that is displayed but I don't think this will work. When you load the webpage, it takes a few seconds for the JavaScript to display the information I want. If I immediately copy the content I only get "Loading..." in the string which I think will happen with this.

Comment: Darn, if you need js to run, you have to use the webbrowser. I'm thinking you're only option is to cycle the webbrowser instances you make. Have you tried just making 10 of them in the beginning and seeing what happens?

Comment: No, I'll give it a shot tomorrow.

Thanks for the help and for your suggestions!

Comment: I got it working by using several WebBrowser instances and Threads. Thanks for you suggestions!

Comment: Yay! congrats man. Had a feeling using several instances of the WebBrowser would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do similar to this , but most of the time it's works for me and sometimes not works perfectly but maybe this will help you,

```
            pageLoaded = false;
            string url = "https://someurl.com" ;
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
            webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
            while (pageLoaded == false)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);       
                Application.DoEvents();  
            }

            result = (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("someid"));
            value = result.InnerText;

        void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            pageLoaded = true;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I managed to solve it another way, by using threads.